# Testing Mosby with Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, tdd, mosby

I'm using Mosby and I would like to test my simple presenter.

```
public class DetailsPresenter extends MvpBasePresenter<DetailsView> {

public void showCountry(Country country) {
    getView().setTitle(country.getName());
    getView().setFlag(country.getFlagUrl());
}
```

}

I've tried to solve it by mocking Presenter:

```
public class DetailsPresenterTest {

private DetailsPresenter mockPresenter;
private DetailsView mockView;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mockPresenter = mock(DetailsPresenter.class);
    mockView = mock(DetailsView.class);

    when(mockPresenter.isViewAttached()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mockPresenter.getView()).thenReturn(mockView);

    doCallRealMethod().when(mockPresenter).showCountry(any(Country.class));
}

@Test
public void shouldShowFlag() throws Exception {
    mockPresenter.showCountry(any(Country.class));
    verify(mockView, times(1)).setFlag(anyString());
}

@Test
public void shouldShowName() throws Exception {
    mockPresenter.showCountry(any(Country.class));
    verify(mockView, times(1)).setTitle(anyString());
}
```

}

But I've got the error

```
    Wanted but not invoked:
detailsView.setFlag(<any string>);
-> at eu.szwiec.countries.details.DetailsPresenterTest.shouldShowFlag(DetailsPresenterTest.java:39)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

I've tried to use also real presenter without a success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use real Presenter and a real country object to invoke `showCountry()`. Everything else doesnt make sense (not testing the real presenter but a mock presenter instance).

```
@Test
public void showFlagAndName(){
   DetailsView mockView = mock(DetailsView.class);
   DetailsPresenter presenter = new DetailsPresenter();
   Country country = new Country("Italy", "italyFlag");

   presenter.attachView(mockView);

   presenter.showCountry(country);

   verify(mockView, times(1)).showCountry("Italy");
   verify(mockView, times(1)).setFlag("italyFlag");
}
```

Comment: technically speaken he does not need a full presenter. It is possible to reduce the *behaviour under test* to one method, but from a strategic point of view, he indeed should test the whole thing.

Comment: Great, thank you for the perfect answer! I have a question about the Country object. Could I use also a mock of it in this case? Or it's a bad practice?

Comment: Whatever works for you. The more real classes you test the better. Otherwise you end up with writing tests against mocks, so that you are actually testing mocks instead real classes. I.e. mocks (with mockito) don't have internal state, whereas your real classes may have state and if branches in your method body.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add some logging to find out what's going on?

I think you do not hit the real method as

```
mockPresenter.showCountry(any(Country.class));
```

does not construct a `Country` object instance but simply passes `null`. So the condition

```
doCallRealMethod().when(mockPresenter).showCountry(any(Country.class));
```

is not met. If you use a less strict condition

```
doCallRealMethod().when(mockPresenter).showCountry(any());
```

you should get a `NullPointerException`.

You may solve this by using a real or a mocked `Country` instance on your method invocation.